# Generate Barcode In Django

Tags: python, python-3.6, barcode-scanner, django-1.11

I am working on asset management app using Django, Now I want to create barcodes for each asset. On the scanning of the barcode, I need to get all the information about the asset, which is the best library to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Use pybarcode and generate the barcode as SVG: http://packages.python.org/pyBarcode/barcode.html#creating-barcodes-as-svg

No problem of image quality in that case.
To read:
https://github.com/dynamsoft-dbr/django-barcode-reader/blob/master/README.md

Comment: On Scanning of the barcode, i need to redirect user to detail page how can i achieve that?

Comment: that link also has code example for barcode creation, not for reading/scanning barcodes.

Comment: Is that helpful?

Comment: looks fine, let me integrate and check with my project

Comment: Is it a web application or an android app?

Comment: web application(Django).

Comment: For example, I need to scan the barcode, once scanned I need to redirect to view page of resource which I scanned.

Comment: look interesting, let me check